# Inserting JQuery in an If Statement inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's been a long time since I code stuff with validation. My problem today is that I am trying to validate a field in which it must have 10 or more than characters. When you press ok, the `jQuery` function should trigger.

```
function pathvalid() {
    var str = document.getElementById("pathenabler");
    var n = str.value.length;
    if (n < 10) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The path that you have entered is either invalid or         incorrect. Please input a valid path.";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Not Good day!";
        $('.actionenabler') .removeClass('chkbox');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this to your OK button

```
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="pathvalid();" />
```

OR

You can write a code using jquery.
Your input button

```
 <input type="button" value="OK" id="btn"/>
```

Your javascript contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
     if($("#pathenabler").text().trim().length < 10){
         $("#demo").append("The path that you have entered is either invalid or incorrect. Please input a valid path.");
      }
       else{
         $("#demo").append("Not Good day!");
         $('.actionenabler').removeClass('chkbox');
      }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `input`s length with `$('#pathenabler').val().length;`.

If I get you right this example might fit your needs ;)

```js
function check() {
  var length = $('#text').val().length;
  alert(length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text" type="text">
<button id="check" onclick="check()">Check input length</button>
```